# Flutter : How to parse JSON Array of objects

Tags: json, flutter

Can anyone tell me how to parse arrays of object in flutter. When I am parsing the json I am getting error as List is not a subtype of type Map<String, dynamic>.

Below is my json file which needs to be parsed. Please help me to fix this issue.

```
[
{
    "empPayslipsId": "2021012000440",
    "month": "Jan",
    "description": "Payslip for JAN 2021 (Month End)",
    "paymentPeriod": "1/1/2021 12:00:00 AM - 1/31/2021 12:00:00 AM",
    "lastAccessBy": "0002\r\n118.200.199.70",
    "lastAccessDate": "20210202",
    "lastAccessTime": "105706",
    "successAccess": "2",
    "failAccess": "2"
}
]









Future<void> loadQueryPeriod(int year, var month) async {
String baseURL = '${domainURL}api/PaySlip?year=$year&month=$month';
try {
  final response = await http.get(baseURL, headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization':
        'Bearer ${Provider.of<UserVM>(navigatorKey.currentContext, listen: false).accessToken}',
  });
  print('UIC PDF response : ${response.body}');
  print(
      'UIC Token response : ${Provider.of<UserVM>(navigatorKey.currentContext, listen: false).accessToken}');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
    print('result type: ${data.runtimeType}');
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
  throw Exception('Download PDF Fail! ${e.toString()}');
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this podo class :

```
// Generated by https://quicktype.io
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final sample = sampleFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<Sample> sampleFromJson(String str) {
    final jsonData = json.decode(str);
    return new List<Sample>.from(jsonData.map((x) => Sample.fromJson(x)));
}

String sampleToJson(List<Sample> data) {
    final dyn = new List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson()));
    return json.encode(dyn);
}

class Sample {
    String empPayslipsId;
    String month;
    String description;
    String paymentPeriod;
    String lastAccessBy;
    String lastAccessDate;
    String lastAccessTime;
    String successAccess;
    String failAccess;

    Sample({
        this.empPayslipsId,
        this.month,
        this.description,
        this.paymentPeriod,
        this.lastAccessBy,
        this.lastAccessDate,
        this.lastAccessTime,
        this.successAccess,
        this.failAccess,
    });

    factory Sample.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Sample(
        empPayslipsId: json["empPayslipsId"],
        month: json["month"],
        description: json["description"],
        paymentPeriod: json["paymentPeriod"],
        lastAccessBy: json["lastAccessBy"],
        lastAccessDate: json["lastAccessDate"],
        lastAccessTime: json["lastAccessTime"],
        successAccess: json["successAccess"],
        failAccess: json["failAccess"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "empPayslipsId": empPayslipsId,
        "month": month,
        "description": description,
        "paymentPeriod": paymentPeriod,
        "lastAccessBy": lastAccessBy,
        "lastAccessDate": lastAccessDate,
        "lastAccessTime": lastAccessTime,
        "successAccess": successAccess,
        "failAccess": failAccess,
    };
}
```

Now inorder to parse json call,

`Sample sample = sampleFromJson(jsonString);`

via this you will get the access to sample PODO class and you can access any object you want.

Comment: Thanks! You save my life :)

Answer (score 2):

Change it to this:

```
 final Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body)[0];
```

This is because your map is inside a list. Look at the square brackets `[ ]` enclosing your map. The map that you need, is at `index[0]` of this list.

Answer (score 0):

The initial data you received by calling a `get` request isn't stored in a map, but rather in a list.

You should do something like this to receive your initial data.

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final List<dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
}
```

From there, they're numerous ways to get the data from your `data` variable. You can use lists here if you want, for example to get the value of `month` in the JSON.

```
final String month = data[0]['month'];
```

If you'd prefer to use Maps, the syntax it'll look like this

```
final Map<String, dynamic> endpointData = data[0];
final String responseKey = 'month';
final var result = endpointData[responseKey];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have data model you can do it like this

```
 fromJsonList(List<dynamic> jsonList) {
    List<YourModel> yourModelList = [];
    jsonList.forEach((jsonModel) {
      menuModelsOfferList.add(YourModel.fromJson(jsonModel));
    });
```